# Page_Action not working it's always grey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```js
function check(tab_id, data, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/') > -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
    }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

I see this code on YouTube and I copy to my project but it's not working how can I adapt it when I go to Linkin page it still grey icon

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "One test",
    "description": "test.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {"scripts": ["test.js"]},
     "page_action": 
    {
        "default_icon": "pic1.png"
    },

   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.jbhired.com; object-src 'self' "
}
```

menifest.json

First extension—please be kind.

Comment: `tab.url` is [only present](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) if you have `"permissions": ["tabs"]` in manifest.

Comment: Oh thanks now it's working LoL  thank you so much

Comment: BTW, you can use [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API. The advantage being less scary permissions warning when the extension is installed from the webstore.

Comment: @wOxxOm  sorry may you explain  - 1   it's stand for what?